# Magento 1.9.1.0 - Upload PDF File Type in Wysiwyg Editor and show PDF Icon

Tags: magento, pdf, wysiwyg, magento-1.9

I made a custom module allowing user to upload `.PDF` file type in `CMS > Pages`. The code used is below:

**app/etc/modules**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
      <active>true</active>
      <codePool>local</codePool>
    </Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
  </modules>
</config>
```

**app/code/local/Pdf/WysiwygFiles/etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config>
  <modules>
    <Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
    </Pdf_WysiwygFiles>
  </modules>
  <adminhtml>
    <cms>
      <browser>
        <extensions>
          <allowed>
            <jpg>1</jpg>
            <jpeg>1</jpeg>
            <png>1</png>
            <gif>1</gif>
            <pdf>1</pdf>
          </allowed>
        </extensions>
      </browser>
    </cms>
  </adminhtml>
</config>
```

This works in `CE-1.9` and does allow to upload PDF file when you click on **Insert Image** button and does not allow to `link` it.

Also, how to add a `pdf preview icon` for each file uploaded ? The result would be like below image

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a link icon from editor to link the uploaded PDF.

Suggestion: Add a PDF icon from insert image and link the PDF after uploading from editor.

Comment: PDF are not stored anywhere. User will upload from desktop.